# Javascript or any script that can change the homepage of the browser

Tags: javascript

Hi is there any webscript that I can load from my webpage which upon loading change the home page of the browser automatically without asking the user's interaction.

I have a code which onclicking asks the user if he wants to set this page as his homepage. I want this script to set it without asking. Could any body help me how I can do this with any script that can run on the webpage.

```
onClick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)'; this.setHomePage('http://example.com');
```

Comment: So you'd like to change my homepage without my "interaction"? Nice idea...

Answer (score 1):

No, in modern browsers it is not possible (Firefox, Chrome, IE>6). Here how google realize it - http://www.google.com/homepage/hp-chrome.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannon use javascript to change your browser inner settings. Same goes with applying any changes to client system. You just need to change you homepage manually.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-to-set-the-home-page

http://www.google.com/homepage/hp-chrome.html

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/change-home-page#ie=ie-11

Answer (score 0):

Because if this could happen with javascript a whole new kind of spam will rise.
Do something better for the internet community please...
You can accomplish something like that with php I guess.